# Can we turn this question into a more generic one?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Can we turn [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1361769/124466) question ("How do I upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 21.04 on i386 architecture?") into something like "I have a 32 bit computer running Ubuntu 18.04, and want to use an operating system with recent versions of packages. What all options do I have?"

That question would not be strictly about Ubuntu, but it would help Ubuntu users continue using their 32 bit computers with a supported operating system.

People still ask [questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361321/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-18-04-lts-32-bit-gui-iso-found-see-added-ref/1361325#1361325) like "How to install 32 bit 18.04?"
Since 18.04 would go EOL in another two years, can we have a generic question with possible migration options?

Comment: Officially, Ubuntu 18.04 was the last Ubuntu variant to ship 32bit.  And while there are a core set of packages for 32-bit in the repos for later releases, those are mostly for driver support and certain packages that require their 32bit compatible counterparts to function.  The only 'migration' options would be to backup data and go to Debian which still supports 32-bit OSes last I checked.